# HTML disable 'id' page move behaviours

Tags: html, css, imagemap

With resources from the web i have created a slide show using purely CSS and HTML. Clicking a linkd on the image map changes the content of the div aligned next to it.

To achieve this i have linked 'href="#"' to 'id=""'. However this results in a 'bookmark' effect on the page where it autmoatically scrolls the page down to the top of the div in which the 'id's reside.

I have managed to get this working well, however, is it possible to disable the behaviour of the page scrolling down but keeping the same functionality?

Thanks!

Code:

**HTML**

```html
<div class="wheelContainer" id="content-slider">
    <ul id="content-slider-inside"> 
        <li id="middle"></li>
        <li id="customer"></li>
        <li id="people"></li>
        <li id="operations"></li>  
        <li id="finance"></li>  
        <li id="community"></li>  
    </ul> 
</div>

<img src="/teams/group-itservice/businesssupport/images/wheel.png" usemap="#Map" border="0" />
<map name="Map" id="Map"><area shape="poly" coords="392,446,295,310,322,276,320,234,478,179,477,332" href="#operations" alt="operations" />
  <area shape="poly" coords="127,446,222,312,260,324,297,311,391,449,252,495" href="#finance" alt="finance" />
  <area shape="poly" coords="218,310,121,446,40,342,40,178,196,235,194,276" href="#community" alt="community" />
  <area shape="poly" coords="259,193,259,27,126,67,41,179,197,234,219,204" href="#customer" alt="customer" />
  <area shape="poly" coords="258,26,259,193,297,207,321,237,475,179,393,70" href="#people" alt="people" /> 
  <area shape="circle" coords="258,258,62" href="#middle" alt="middle" />
</map>
```

**CSS**

```css
#content-slider {  
    width: 480px;  
    overflow: hidden;  
    height: 515px;  
}

#content-slider-inside {  
    list-style: none;  
    height: 515px;      // these 3 lines  
    overflow: scroll;   // help Opera  
    overflow-y: hidden; // behave
}  

#content-slider-inside li {  
    width: 350px;  
    height: 515px;  
    padding-top:50px;
    padding-left:20px;
}
```

Comment: Don't use a #. #'s are for bookmarks. Use a non reserved character.

Answer (score 0):

To keep your ID references you can have an onClick return false. This should stop the page from scrolling, but does that break your other actions?

```
<area shape="poly" coords="127,446,222,312,260,324,297,311,391,449,252,495" href="#finance" alt="finance" onClick="return false;" />
```

Answer (score -1):

On the element that you wish to disable the default behaviour on, use [`preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault).

### JavaScript:

```
var areas = $(document).querySelectorAll('area[href^="#"]'), i;

for(i = 0; i < areas.length; i+=1) {
    areas[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }, false);
}
```